# Getting current logged user in spring + angular

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am using Spring Security in my Spring Boot app and i want to get the current logged user from `Principal#getName` but i have an error of template resolution and it contains the username that i want to get.

This is my controller:

```
import java.security.Principal;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class PageController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/api/loggeduser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printWelcome(ModelMap model, Principal principal) {
        String name = null;
        if (principal !=null) {
            name = principal.getName();
        }
        model.addAttribute("username", name);

        return name;
   } 

}
```

And this is my AngularJs function to get the logged in user:

```
app.controller('Usercontr', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/api/loggeduser").success(function (data) {
        $scope.nom = data;  
        console.log($scope.nom) 
    })
});
```

And here's the error:

> Error resolving template "kamel.mili", template might not exist or
>   might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

`Kamel.mili` is the logged in username. Can you please help me. I am using thymeleaf for just the login page and everything else is html + AngularJs. I don't know why thymeleaf had it's hand on this controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `@ResponseBody` annotation to your controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/loggeduser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model, Principal principal ) { ... }
```

When you're using the `@Controller` stereotype annotation, Spring MVC will try to resolve your `String` return value to a `View`, hence the error:

> Error resolving template "kamel.mili", template might not exist or
>   might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

If you want to just write the return value to the response body, you can either make your controller a `@RestController` or annotate specific controllers with `@ResponseBody`.

This is kinda off topic but since you're using client side view rendering, that `ModelMap` is pretty useless. You can safely get rid of it.

Comment: it seems that i have problem retreiving data it can't be parsed is it

Answer (score 3):

You need to do like following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/loggeduser", produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
public ResponseEntity<String> findMessagesForUser(Principal principal) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(principal.getName(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Or you can use response builders:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/loggeduser", produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
public ResponseEntity<String> findMessagesForUser(Principal principal) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(principal.getName());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have properly configured template resolver, then you should check yours templates. Return string from printWelcome() should match with one of the view created in your view/template folder.In your case, you are returning user name it self, i guess it should be welcome kind of page.